# Creating a choice column (IF statement/display specific choices)

Tags: infopath, column, filter, choice-field

I create an customize list. There are two choice columns and I want to achive the result is, 
If column A select "aa" column B will only display some specific choices, such as "1.1 aaa" "1.2 bbb"
Same as above said if column A select other choice, column will show other specific choices.
How should I do? Is it possible to come true with the "Rule" feature by Infopath?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of what you are looking for is called 'cascading filters'.

It can be achieved in 2 ways, one of which with InfoPath.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HnLhXVQf-M) that explains very clearly.

your other option is to create a term set in the metadata/taxonomy term store where you have first level and second level terms. Unlike the InfoPath solution, in this case you will not have 2 different columns for your values but only one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a rookie on sharepoint 2013. It's just what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Cascading Dropdown using jquery.SPServices. Download the library [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/), and save it to your site (for example, you could save it at /_catalogs/masterpage/js).

Assuming you have 3 lists:

List A has 2 fields: ID, NameA

List B has 3 fields: ID, NameB, AID (this is a lookup field to the list A item)

List C (here is the list who has 2 choice columns) has 3 fields: ID, TitleA (lookup to list A), TitleB (lookup to list B).

Then on your list C form (add / edit form), you could add the following code:

```
// Refer to the library
<script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/js/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

// Start cascading dropdown code
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "B", // The list who has reference to list A
        relationshipListParentColumn: "AID", // The 'foreign key' of the relationshipList
        relationshipListChildColumn: "NameB", // The value (anything you want to display) field of the relationshipList
        parentColumn: "TitleA", // The field on list C which refer to the list A (this is the first choice column)
        childColumn: "TitleB", // The field on list C which refer to the list B (this is the second choice column)
        debug: true
    });
});
</script>
```